# How to set X-RateLimit-Reset with express-rate-limit?

Tags: javascript, express, handler, rate-limiting

I want to set a custom time that a user must wait if they hit a rate limit. I am using [express-rate-limit](https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit) and *thought* I could do this by setting a custom `X-RateLimit-Reset` in the [`handler`](https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit#handler). I can set this value, but it does not appear to have any effect.

As an extreme example, I tried to block them for a very long time in the future using the following in my handler:

```
res.setHeader('X-RateLimit-Reset', Date.now() + 100000000000)
```

Console logging `res` after this results in something correct:

```
 'x-ratelimit-reset': [ 'X-RateLimit-Reset', 1566112162159 ] // <-- far in the future
```

However, after doing this, a user is still able to call the function that should have been rate limited. How can I set a custom reset time for a user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, as you've not mentioned it, I'm assuming you're using the default MemoryStore that comes with the express-rate-limit. So to answer your question, you don't have to manually set the `x-ratelimit-reset` header in the response, the package does it for you.

- So if you're using the default MemoryStore, the configuration looks like this,

```
app.use(
    RateLimit({
        windowMs: 10 * 60 * 1000 , // 10 minutes
        max: 100, // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
        message: 'You have exceeded the 100 requests in 10 minutes limit!',
    })
);
```

- And, if you're using a store other than the default one, you can add the store config in it,

```
app.use(
    RateLimit({
        store: new MongoStore({
            uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/your-db-name',
            expireTimeMs: 10 * 60 * 1000 // 10 minutes
        }),
        windowMs: 10 * 60 * 1000 , // 10 minutes
        max: 100, // limit each IP to 100 requests per windowMs
        message: 'You have exceeded the 100 requests in 10 minutes limit!',
    })
);
```

Just to note here, `rate-limt-redis` store has some problems with `x-ratelimit-reset` header and doesn't work as expected. So, you can go ahead with other options.